# How to prevent Vue.js hidden element pop-in on page load?

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to Vue.js and I have a (block) element that should be initially hidden on page load. I'm coming from a pure JS mixed with JQuery background so normally I would initially set `display:none` on the element use JQuery's show/hide methods etc.

I have the showing and hiding working correctly with Vue but a side effect is that the element flashes on the screen briefly on page load until the Vue setup is complete and it knows to hide the element. Setting `display:none` breaks the show/hide presumably because the elements class prop has higher precedence. Setting `opacity:0` also seems to be overriding anything Vue is doing so that breaks the show/hide too. `!important` on the Vue animation classes does not help either.

The embedded sandbox below might not be the best way to reproduce this, and I suppose it might be system dependent too (speed, memory etc.) but surely this must be a common enough situation with some solution that I've missed.

```js
VUE = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        showFullpageSpinner: false
    }
});

setTimeout(function() {
    VUE.showFullpageSpinner = true;
    setTimeout(function() { VUE.showFullpageSpinner = false; }, 1500);
}, 1500);
```

```css
.fullpage-spinner-underlay {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
    z-index: 9999;
}
.fullpageSpinner-enter-active, .fullpageSpinner-leave-active {
    transition: opacity .25s;
}
.fullpageSpinner-enter, .fullpageSpinner-leave-to {
    opacity: 0;
} 
.css-spinner {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
}
.css-spinner:before {
    content: 'Loading...';
    position: absolute;
}
.css-spinner:not(:required):before {
    content: '';
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top: 3px solid #daac35;
    border-right: 3px solid transparent;
    animation: spinner .7s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: spinner .7s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes spinner {
    to {-ms-transform: rotate(360deg);}
    to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
@-webkit-keyframes spinner {
    to {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
    to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
@-moz-keyframes spinner {
    to {-moz-transform: rotate(360deg);}
    to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
.fullpage-loading-spinner {
    left: 50%;
    top: 45%;
    margin-left: -40px;
    margin-top: -55px;
}
.fullpage-loading-spinner:BEFORE {
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <transition name="fullpageSpinner">
    <div v-if="showFullpageSpinner" class="fullpage-spinner-underlay">
        <div class="css-spinner fullpage-loading-spinner"></div>
    </div>
  </transition>
</div>
```

Comment: have `showFullpageSpinner = true` by default?

Comment: @A.Lau but I don't want it shown initially. That's the problem, it should be hidden until something happens on the page later in response to some event. The problem is when it briefly flashes on the screen on page load. `display:none` on `.fullpage-spinner-underlay` would normally fix this but doing that breaks Vue's show/hide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem seems to be solvable with the [v-cloak](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-cloak) directive.

> This directive will remain on the element until the associated Vue instance finishes compilation. Combined with CSS rules such as `[v-cloak] { display: none }`, this directive can be used to hide un-compiled mustache bindings until the Vue instance is ready.

Example:

```css
[v-cloak] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div v-if="showFullpageSpinner" class="fullpage-spinner-underlay" v-cloak>
  <div class="css-spinner fullpage-loading-spinner"></div>
</div>
```